# jquery effects different on different browsers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery to shift positions of multiple divs. The effect i used is working on firefox( i am using firefox4). It is working as i want it on the same. But when i test it on chrome it's not the same.! Here is the link to the page http://bit.ly/lsTwbg

I forgot to mention that you have to click middle box! sorry

Comment: You should paste your code here to make the question permanent for future people. And by the way you should paste Screenshots. For example I don't have Firefox and my Chrome (I think) does it correctly.

Comment: what effects u r talking about?

Comment: I usually find Chrome has a litte too much salt for my taste as well.

Comment: In my FF & GC , they are the same

Comment: does it come from bottom on both!

Comment: i forgot to mention that you have to click middle box!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to initially set the bottom-style of #seriously-main-wrapper.

In Develeper-tools you can see, the initially bottom in FF is something like 500px(exactly 511px for me ), in Chrome not present.
So the animation runs in FF from 511px to 30px(downwards) and in Chrome from 0 to 30px(upwards)

Comment: Thank you for the clue...... Instead i worked on it from top and it is now working!!

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I can see, the different "Versions"...

My guess:
Don't use the animate on the `margin`. You should work with `position: absolute` in a `relative` div. Use the `animate()` on the `top` and the `left` css-attribute.

Comment: but i tried removing portion of code and only two statements stand out as culprits.. 

`code`$("#seriously-main-wrapper").animate({"bottom": "20px"},{duration:5000,queue:false},"slow");
                $('#animal-scale').animate({"margin-top": "0px","margin-left": "229px"},{duration:5000,queue:false},"slow");`code`

Comment: All other statements work as they're supposed to even the rest of margin changes